# Winscp: webdav connection failed: authentication failed. rejected basic challange

Tags: authentication, webdav, winscp

I set up a script to connect on webdav server.

I run winscp with this parameters:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /script=script.txt /log=winscp.log /ini=nul
```

Then, the script is:

```
open davs://user@company.com:password@querty.sandbox.company.com/in/my.servlet/webdav/Catalogs/company/
synchronize remote -mirror D:\winscptest\files\ /in/my.servlet/webdav/Catalogs/company/
close
exit
```

When i run the command, authentication fails, with this output:

```
Connecting to host...
Authenticating...
Access denied.
Authentication failed.
Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge
Connection failed.
```

If i configure the connection in winscp (with GUI), all works fine.

Can someone help me to configure the script correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@MartinPrikryl thanks for your attention.

I contacted webdav server 's administrator, to check log their side, and he noticed that account was blocked, may be to many tries with wrong password.

Then i understand that username and password must be url enconded to use it in a script.

@MartinPrikryl great work with winscp, i love it.

Bye